# Webscraping question on appending several values to a single row with beautifulsoup

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Lets say i want to scrape imdb for top 10 movies. I would like to fetch the title for the movies and the cast members for the movies.

Im easily able to fetch the title of the  movies and append them to a list. The problem is i dont know how to append several values to a single row. Let say the first movie has 3 actors, the second movie has 5 actors, how can append the actors to a list so that the 3 actors on in first movie are in row 1 of the list and the 5 actors from the second movie are in row 2 and so on.

Comment: You could use e.g. a nested array, or nest an object into your array (aka. “list”).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, will look into that!

Comment: Question could be improved by adding some more details, not least by an example of expected output - Thanks

Comment: The idea is to ultimately be able to create a dataset out of the data retireved, in other words create an excel file where each row has the data corresponding to the specific movie on that row. Movie 1 with corresponding actors on row 1, movie 2 with corresponding actors on row 2 etc. The problem is right now for data retrieved on actors a new row gets created each time a actor name is retrieved, so if movie 1 has 3 actors the movie list has a lenght of one row and the actor row has e lenght of three rows. Sorry if im making this problem complicated as im quite the beginner in coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Just a general approach, cause there is no code provided in your question.

Request the webiste  (example [top 250 movies](https://www.imdb.com/chart/top/?ref_=nv_mv_250)) and cook your soup:

```
response = requests.get('http://www.imdb.com/chart/top')
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
```

Create your empty list that should store your results:

```
data = []
```

Iterate over the result set of your selection (example [top 250 movies](https://www.imdb.com/chart/top/?ref_=nv_mv_250)) and append a dict per iteration to your list:

```
for e in soup.select('.titleColumn a'):
    data.append({
        'title':e.text,
        'director':e['title'].split('(dir.),')[0],
        'actors':e['title'].split('(dir.),')[-1]
    })
```

Print your `data` or create a data frame from your list of dicts and :

```
pd.DataFrame(data)
```

#### Output

```
    title               director                actors
0   Die Verurteilten    Frank Darabont          Tim Robbins, Morgan Freeman
1   Der Pate            Francis Ford Coppola    Marlon Brando, Al Pacino
2   Der Pate 2          Francis Ford Coppola    Al Pacino, Robert De Niro
```

Comment: Thanks fam i appreciate the help! Will see if I'm able to get it to work as im working with a similar problem on another page i just used imdb to make explaining my problem easier! Peace!